# NavigationView вызывает java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-navigation-view

Ошибка ссылается на строку `View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);`
Вот мой код. У себя не получается словить эту ошибку на своих устройствах Android 5.1 и Android 7. Так же на эмуляторах не вызывается это ошибка. Но отчеты приходят с этой ошибкой

```
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) 
    findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    ID_NicknameTextView = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.id_nickname);
    ID_clanTextView = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.id_clan);
```

Мой `layout`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_profile"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/Navigation"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main2_drawer" />/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Библиотека поддержки

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

Для Android 7, 7.1

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2724)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2789)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1527)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:110)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:203)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6251)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1063)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:924)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.robin.vitalij.tanksapi.Retrofit.activity.Activity_profile.onCreate (Activity_profile.java:235)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6666)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1118)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2677)
```

Для Android 6

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2576)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2658)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1492)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:207)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5737)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:789)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.robin.vitalij.tanksapi.Retrofit.activity.Activity_profile.onCreate (Activity_profile.java:235)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6331)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1113)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2523)
```

Отчеты для Android 4.4, 5.1

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2389)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2441)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:151)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1354)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:110)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5345)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:828)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:644)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.robin.vitalij.tanksapi.Retrofit.activity.Activity_profile.onCreate (Activity_profile.java:235)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:5343)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1088)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2343)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Попробуйте](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33202442/3212712) добавлять `header` не в разметке, но программно:

```
View header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.nav_header_main, null);
navigationView.addHeaderView(header);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Проверю у себя